# plotting spectra using r-studio in latex

Tags: graphics, graphs

[image]

Hi all. How can I create Raman graphs in latex? I have allready plotted it but I couldn't got it using Latex. So how can I merge between two software?

[image: Raman spectra for different forms of raw material]

Comment: If you want to re-plot it, we need data. Since you have already plotted it, save the picture as `raman.png` and use: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{raman}
    \caption[Raman spectra]{This is Raman spectra of samples}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}`.

Comment: Dear Kumar Thanks so much but how can I insert the left picture with the other two graphs (as you see) in attached picture?

Comment: If you're going to do much more TeX and r together you might look into using knitr (http://yihui.name/knitr/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to re-plot it, we need data. Since you have already plotted it, save the picture as `raman.png` and then use `\icludegraphics` from `graphicx` package.

You can use `minipage`s to align them as you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \caption{Some picture}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{raman}
    \caption{Some picture}

    \medskip
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{raman}
    \caption{Some picture}
    \end{minipage}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to procrastinate further, you may consider using `subfigure` from `subcaption` package or `subfloat` from `subfig` package.

Comment: i am so thankful for your patience and cooperation

Comment: @WathiqZayed You are welcome. :-)